# Spring Data JPA delete from many to many relationship problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In my project I use Spring data jpa. I have tables for many to many relationship. My entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SPEC")
    public class SpecJpa {
        @Id
        private int id;
        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "Creator_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
        private UsersJpa usersJpa;
        @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;


        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="SPEC_PARTS",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_PARTS", referencedColumnName="id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_SPEC", referencedColumnName="id")
        )
    private Set<PartsJpa> partsJpa;
    //---------------
```

And Parts:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTS")
public class PartsJpa {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EXPORT", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private ExportJpa exportJpa;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TYPE", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private TypesJpa typesJpa;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    private Set<SpecJpa> specJpa;
```

Now in Controller I try to delete one row from table parts:

```
@PostMapping("deletePart")
public String deletePart(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    partsService.deleteById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    return "redirect:/parts";

}
```

But I have exception:

> ferential integrity constraint violation:
>   "FK9Y4MKICYBLJWPENACP4298I49: PUBLIC.PARTS FOREIGN KEY(ID_EXPORT)
>   REFERENCES PUBLIC.EXPORT(ID) (1)"; SQL statement: /* delete
>   com.aleksandr0412.demo.entitiesjpa.ExportJpa */ delete from EXPORT
>   where id=? [23503-200]], SQL: /* delete
>   com.aleksandr0412.demo.entitiesjpa.ExportJpa */ delete from EXPORT
>   where id=? 2020-05-25 19:16:31.630  WARN 13387 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23503, SQLState:
>   23503

In my db for this entities I have 3 tables: Parts, Spec and Spec_parts. As I understand to solve this problem, I firstly should delete rows in table spec_parts, and after this I can delete row from table parts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `partsService` implementation, I would recommend you first fetch the resource you are about to delete `(i.e the PartsJpa)` using the given `id` from the controller.
Next set its specJpa to `null` or `emptySet`, then call the delete method afterwards.

For this to work, ensure that method `setSpecJpa(SpecJpa specJpa)` and `setPartJpa(PartJpa partJpa)` are properly implemented.

I hope you find this helpful.